# How to overwrite an existing html file from textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to create a normal HTML editor where it's functions are similar to Windows Notepad. Let's say we've written a file and wanted to save it. So the `SaveFileDialog` comes up and asking us where we want to save it. Then we modified it, and in Notepad you usually just use `Ctrl+S` to save it again. And this time, no `SaveFileDialog` will show up. In other words, the existing file has been overwritten. This is what I wanted to achieve. Here's the code I have so far:

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        SaveFileDialog sfd = default(SaveFileDialog);
            string location = null;
            string sourcecode = textBox1.Text;

            sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            location = sfd.FileName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sfd.FileName))
            {
                saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
            File.Copy(sfd.FileName, Path.Combine(location, Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName)), true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you ask has nothing to do with textboxes or HTML. You need to track the state of your file. You can do that by storing the file's location in a field or property. If the field is empty, it means the file is new and you need to load open `Save As`. Otherwise, just write the contents to the original location, eg with `File.WriteAllText()`. `File.Copy` has nothing to do with *saving*

Comment: PS: DON'T put the "Save" functionality in an event handler. It's *NOT* an event handler. It's a separate method that can be called in response to a *lot* of different events

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the idea. I tried adding a function File.WriteAllText(); in the code but it still has not work. Maybe if anyone could redo my code, it would be appreciated.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. There are no magic solutions either. You have to *write* code that writes data to files, stores paths etc. The snippet you posted has little to do with what you try to achieve. Text editors were very popular as tutorials a few years ago. Stop looking for magic solutions and *think* how the program should be structured and what it should do. Or simply search for a tutorial, eg google for `SaveFileDialog`. Saving files is used in all relevant samples and documentation